# Command to restore filesystem to state after installation of the OS

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, raspberry-pi, raspbian

How can I wipe all the changes to the filesystem **since** installing the OS?
 It's not that I want to destroy the files because they contain sensitive data or anything like that; I just want to start over without reformatting the SD card, etc. (I'm on a Raspberry Pi, running Occidentalis, which is basically Raspbian, which is basically ARM Debian). I know about `rm`, but I don't want to delete the OS -- just all the stuff I've done since running it the first time.

Comment: I would be careful with any answer I get to this question, what you are asking is very difficult to do without damaging the system. This is something I have had to learn the hard way after giving an answer to a similar question with the best of intentions only to cause damage someone's system. The safest way to do this is if you have a backup of the virgin system and then restore the backup.

Comment: @Graeme That's a great point. But, I just reinstalled my OS 2 days ago; there's nothing important on my Pi. But thanks for the warning!

Comment: You say you want to "wipe the drive clean" but then you say that you want to keep the OS. You can't do both. I think you're trying to describe something more like restoring a backup (that you never made) of the drive. You might also be able to iterate through all files by creation time, but that might cause inconsistencies.

Comment: @wutaz Basically, I'm trying to do a "factory restore" of the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always a bad idea to try and get things back to the way things were before (unless one uses a tool like Git to keep a full file history).

One would be better off using tools on another computer to make a fresh install of the OS on the SD card.   Occidentalis v0.2 can be downloaded here: http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-raspberry-pi-educational-linux-distro/occidentalis-v0-dot-2

Comment: Yeah, I have Occidentalis on my laptop. But thanks! That's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

The find utility contains options to select filenames based on date or owner.  You could find every file since a particular time or not owned by root.

Once you're sure **find** is finding what you want, use the -exec option

`$ find /usr ... -exec rm {} +`

The **+** tells find to execute the command in parallel.

Comment: Any approach using find is potentially damaging, particularly the above with suggests removing all files under `/usr`.